# ui-router change url after $state.go

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a route:

```
$stateProvider.state('keeper.telepay.category', {
    url: '/category-{id}/country-{cid}/region-{rid}'
}
```

In all cases when I use $state.go with this route, I want to change **rid** to 'all' if it's value is '0', so my url'll be like

**/category-1/country-195/region-all**

I've tried to do it in $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart'), but with no luck. Any suggestions || directions would be very appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Here what I've tried on $stateChange:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    if(toState.name == 'keeper.telepay.category' && toState.params.rid == 0) {
        toState.params.rid = 'all';
    }
}
```

Comment: Should probably post what you have tried in `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart')` because that's what people are going to suggest.

Comment: maybe u can start a trial with [$urlMatchFactory](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.$urlMatcherFactory) to create your own param type.

Comment: Good suggestion, thx

Comment: I had a similar issue.  I had to use `$urlRouterProvider.when /(\/tasks)$/i, ($injector, $location)-> "#{$location.path}/1"`in order to append the index to the path to force it.  I think the `$urlRouter` operates first.  However you may also need to declare this before declaring the state in your config. Order takes precedence in states wtih similar URLs matchers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accidently I've stumbled to this link http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/feature-1.0/interfaces/params.paramdeclaration.html#squash

So the pure solution is:

```
$stateProvider.state('keeper.telepay.category', {
    url: '/category-{id}/country-{cid}/region-{rid}',
    params: {
        cid: '195',
        rid: {
            value: '0',
            squash: "all" <-- do the trick
        }
    }
});
```

**And here is description:**

Configures how a default parameter value is represented in the URL when the current parameter value is the same as the default value.

*There are three squash settings:*

**false**: The parameter's default value is not squashed. It is encoded and included in the URL

**true**: The parameter's default value is omitted from the URL. If the parameter is preceeded and followed by slashes in the state's url declaration, then one of those slashes are omitted. This can allow for cleaner looking URLs.

**"arbitrary string"**: The parameter's default value is replaced with an arbitrary placeholder of your choice.